# Java 8 forEach cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java-8

I wanted to learn the differences between Java 8 and Java 7. At the moment I am looking into the Java 8 `forEach` loop.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("hello","my","name","is","test");
        strings.stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
    }
}
```

This code is generating the following error for me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
s cannot be resolved to a variable
Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
s cannot be resolved to a variable

at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

I am sure that the JDK aswell as the JRE are Java 8, since the compuler can recognize the `forEach` method from the `List` but not the `->` parameter.

Comment: This will give you an idea http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_8_from_a_for

Comment: It sounds like a Java 7 vs Java 8 bug. What is the output from your program if you run `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));`?

Comment: I believe I know what is happening. The JRE is `1.8.0_25` as output by `System.getProperty()`. However, the JDK is 1.7. God knows where Eclipse has that setting from though.

Comment: Good, issue resolved then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem by reinstalling the JRE, JDK and created a completely new installation of eclipse. 
Apparently the old eclipse was still linked to some leftovers from a Java 7 JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Test you java version in command prompt 
c:> java -version

If it gives 1.7 then your JDK is not updated to 1.8.

In eclipse you can windows->preferences->java->compiler and select compiler compliance level as 1.8